# Making csv from txt files

Tags: csv, awk

I have a lot of txt files like this:

```
Title 1
Text 1(more then 1 line)
```

And I would like to make one csv file from all of them that it will look like this:

```
Title 1,Text 1
Title 2,Text 2
Title 3,Text 3
etc
```

How could I do it? I think that awk is good for it but don't know how to realize it.

Comment: It would help if you formatted your code in a readable manner and showed some example input data and what you'd like the output data to look like. You say "bash", but the only "bash" is the `for` loop and the redirection. The bulk of it is AWK.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest:

```
paste -d, file1 file2 file3
```

To handle large numbers of files, max 40 per output file (untested, but close):

```
xargs -n40 files... echo >tempfile
num=1
for line in $(<tempfile)
do
    paste -d, $line >outfile.$num
    let num=num+1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is approximately what you posted with some improvements.

```
for text in *
do
    awk 'BEGIN {q="\""; print q}
         NR==1 {
                gsub(" "," ")    # why?
                gsub("Title: *","")
                print
               }
         NR>1  {
                gsub(" "," ")    # why?
                gsub("Content: *","")
                gsub(q,q q)
                print
               }

         END {print q}' "$text" >> ../final
done
```

**Edit:**

If you have a bunch of files that consist of only two lines, try this:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/,/' file*.txt
```

If the files contain more than two lines each then it will put each pair of lines on the same line separated by a comma.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. In result I get one column, not two columns.

Comment: @llokely: does it work better if you change the first `print` to `printf $0`? It would really help a lot if you included some examples in your question.

Comment: @llokely: Well, if you don't provide more information then there's really nothing more I can do. I can't read your mind and at this point I'm doing little more than guessing.

Comment: I have files in one directory and I need to make one csv file from them and I need that first row will go to the first column and other content will go to the second column. I had such script to make it but I lost it and script which I provided was a alpha version of it and it doesn't work but I think that it could help in way to make a good one.

Comment: My files contains more then 2 lines and separitng other lines by comma will not be good.

Comment: @llokely: I give up. Until you can specify *completely* what you have and what you want, nobody can help you. Please see read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Here are wrote in better way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352865/making-csv-from-text-using-awk

Comment: @llokely: No, it's not. That shows that your files consist of two lines. If that's not the case, then it's an incomplete specification. You shouldn't post clarifications of a question as a new question. You should edit the original. My `sed` command above does exactly what your new question asks for.

Comment: Yes, it works very well, but only if I have 2 lines. And If I my text has more then 2 lines it doesn't work correct.

Comment: @llokely: I don't think you've ever said what you want done with the extra lines.

Answer (score 0):

Given 3 files containing the following data:

**file1.txt**

```
Heading 1
Text 1
Text 2
```

**file2.txt**

```
Heading 2
Text 1
```

**file3.txt**

```
Heading 3
Text 1
text 2
Text 3
```

The expected results are:

```
Heading 1,Text 1,Text 2 
Heading 2,Text1 
Heading 3,Text 1,text 2,Text 3
```

This is accomplished using the program createcsv.awk below invoked as

```
gawk -f createcsv.awk file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

**createcsv.awk**

```
{
  if (1 == FNR) {
     # It is the first line of a new file
     if (csvline != "") {
       # First file or empty files we can ignore
       print csvline;
     }
     csvline = "";
     delimiter = "";
  }
  csvline = csvline delimiter $0;
  if ("" == delimiter) { delimiter="," }
}
END{
 print csvline;
}
```

Comment: Or invoke as gawk -f createcsv.awk file*.txt