# Making csv from text using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have a lot of txt files like this:

```
Title 1
Text 1
```

And I would like to make one csv file from all of them that it will look like this:

```
Title 1,Text 1
Title 2,Text 2
Title 3,Text 3
etc
```

How could I do it using awk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making csv from txt files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313247/making-csv-from-txt-files). Please edit your original question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing any more detail, the following answers look like good options:

```
awk '{printf "%s,", $0; getline; print}'
# every second line gets merged with the previous line
```

or

```
awk \
'
  $0 ~ /^Title/ {printf "\n"}
  {printf "%s,", $0}
'
# every line that starts with Title starts
# a newline and the rest is merged into one
# long line separated by commas.
```